# Bootstrap css issue - Overwriting to new class name

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, webpack, css-loader

I am building a my new App with React Starter from following Git Repo :
https://github.com/alicoding/react-webpack-babel

Some reason, everytime I have a new class in "index.scss" It generated as weird new class name.

For Example , If I wrote new class as :

```
   .container {
       max-width:1000px;
   }
```

It becomes something like :

```
    .src-style-___index__container___32Sga {
        max-width: 1000px;
      }
```

Anyone know why it's doing this ?
What's the proper way to use this method? or
What if I do not want to use this method ?

Please be advised.

Thanks,

Comment: In your example your selector adresses an html element not a class. Maybe your compiler does this only with unknown elements?

Comment: sorry, I missed a dot "." in front. Now It's a class.

Answer (score -2):

You should add `.` before your class in your scss file.
change `container` to `.container`

Comment: Sorry, Changed to .container.
Still having an issue.